# how to create "if" by values of an array elements in php

Tags: php

i have an php array with Unknown number of elements (1 to 6 elements). the elements are boolean (false or true)
i want to write an if block that do some statements if all of array element are true and do some other statement if at least one of element value is false. can you help me?

Comment: It would be clearer if you show an example of what you mean with what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this =)

```
$myarray = [true,true,true,true,true];
// no true elements
if (!in_array(true, $myarray)) {
   echo 'no true elements';
}
// no false elements
if (!in_array(false, $myarray)) {
   echo 'no false elements';
}
// at least one false element
if (in_array(false, $myarray)) {
   echo 'at least one false element';
}
```